# jQuery scrolling div top

Tags: jquery, sticky

I've got a div that scrolls with the page after it clears the header section. Seems to work fine, but when scrolling back to the top, it won't go back to the exact spot that it started at when he page loaded.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 266) {
        var $myDiv = $("#scrollingNavigation");
        $myDiv.stop();
        $myDiv.animate({ marginTop: ($(window).scrollTop()) - 266 });
    }
    else {
        ($(window).scrollTop() - 266);
    }
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="scrollingNavigation">My content and image here</div>
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/masada/zZgcG/4/

Try scrolling the window slowly, and it will leave only about 8-10px from the top. Scroll fast and the div will rest back at the top at all different kinds of space from the top. 
Rather confusing.

Answer (score 1):

a little change to your code..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var $myDiv = $("#scrollingNavigation");
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $myDiv.stop();
            $myDiv.animate({ marginTop: ($(window).scrollTop()) + 50 });
        }
        else {
            $myDiv.stop();
            $myDiv.css({ marginTop: 0 });
        }
    });
});
```

please find working demo here "http://jsfiddle.net/zZgcG/10/".

Comment: Thanks, but this kills the scrolling altogether. Your example doesn't show any scrolling for the div, regardless of how far one scrolls down.

Comment: Right it did not work before as i mistakenly had put `-` in stead of `+`. Now have edited the code and it seems working fine. Please check at the updated link.

Comment: Ashwini, it now works fine. Thank you VERY MUCH for your help in this matter!

Comment: @MPR most welcome and you can select it as the correct answer so that others may also get benefited from the same.